# KeyEvent won't change background color of JPanels

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyboard-events

I want the KeyEvent to change the background color of my JPanels. Nothing happens when I press anything on the keyboard. One of my applications specifications is that I need a 'Customized component extended from JPanel.' which is why I have another class for my graphics panel.

My problem is when G is pressed nothing happens but my center panel should turn green...

Here is code for part of my application.

```
public class Maths extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{    
private JPanel pNorth = new JPanel();
private JPanel pSouth = new JPanel();
private JPanel pCenter = new JPanel();
private JPanel pEast = new JPanel();
private JPanel pWest = new JPanel();
private File file;
private JPanel pDraw = new GraphicsPanel();

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    new Maths();

}

public Maths()
{
    mainFrame = new JFrame();

    mainFrame.setTitle("Maths Test Game");
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainFrame.setSize(1200, 800);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainFrame.add(pNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainFrame.add(pSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainFrame.add(pCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.add(pEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainFrame.add(pWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

    pNorth.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pSouth.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pCenter.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pEast.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pWest.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel 
{
    GraphicsPanel() 
    {
        // set a preferred size for the custom panel.
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        // set blue color for drawing
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // face
        g.drawOval(90, 70, 80, 80);
        // eyes
        g.drawOval(110, 95, 5, 5);
        g.drawOval(145, 95, 5, 5);
        // nose
        g.drawLine(130, 95, 130, 115);
        // mouth
        g.drawArc(113, 115, 35, 20, 0, -180);

    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_G)
    {
        pCenter.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{

}

}
```

Comment: I notice that you have some unnecessary code included in your question. Could you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the specific issue?

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Which code is unnecessary? I added the graphics class because I thought that might be the issue. that maybe i needed my keylisteners in that class.

Comment: My problem is when G is pressed nothing happens but my center panel should turn green...

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of reasons this is probably not working, generally, you don't want to attach `KeyListener`s to top level containers like `JFrame`, as they is simply to many things that can get in the way and prevent the frame from raising key events.

Instead, use the key bindings API.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details